# NTFS Permissions for Anonymous Web User Account in IIS7 for ASP.Net applications

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, ntfs

I'm wondering if anyone has much experience with the minimal permission set for the Anonymous Web User account that is required for an ASP.Netv3.5 applications to run in IIS7?

I'm used to setting up ASP.NETv1.1 Applications running under II6. Under that we typicaly gave the application pool (Worker Process) accounts pretty broad permissions but the anonymous web user accounts (e.g. IUSR) had very tight permissions. We only gave it read access to the files within the web application itself, we didn't give it any access to the system drive (C:), and everything worked just fine.

For some reason, whenever I try to setup one of our developers asp.netv3.5 applications under IIS7, no matter what the application, the anonymous web user account seems to demand read attribute and list content NTFS permissions to pretty much the entire C: drive. Depending upon the application it also is looking for read access to some .DLL's in the system32 folder.

I don't mind giving such access to the Application Pool Accounts (IIS_IUSERS in IIS7 or what used to be called IIS_WPG in IIS6) but  I'm thinking the Anonymous Web User Accounts shouldn't be looking for that kind of access. Anyone have similar experience with ASP.NET apps under IIS7 (Server 2008R2), do they really require read attributes and list content for all of C: for Anonymous Web User accounts?

Comment: This would probably be a better fit on serverfault.com

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981949

Comment: For anyone interested, I found the source of the problem. We were NOT using "Pass Through Authentication" and apparently when you specify a specific account to access resources on a path where the website files are hosted ("Connect As"), IIS7 uses that account not just for access of those specific resources but alot of the access to system level resources that the Worker Process account would otherwise make.